# MongoDB Update document and add new field

Tags: mongodb

I am making a simple todo-list app in `Mongo`

Here is an example record:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("53c6e4a86929336e097b18d6"), 
   "list_id" : 7, 
   "notes" : { 
     "note_id_3" : { 
          "description" : "buy all the bacon", "done" : false }}}`

I have created a unique index on the `list_id` attribute (rather than having users each list accessed will have a unique `list_id` and the accompanying notes will be stored that way. I am trying to now add a new `note` to the `notes` hash.

Following their documentation I have tried this:

```
db.todos.update(
     {list_id: 7}, 
     { $push: { 
          notes: { 
            note_id_6: { “description”: “it works”, “done”: true}}}})
```

as well as

```
db.todos.update(
         {list_id: 7}, 
         { $set: { 
              "notes.note_id_6": { 
                “description”: “it works”, “done”: true}}}})
```

but am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` and I'm not sure what part of my syntax is incorrrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `“` (double quotes):

```
db.todos.update(
 {list_id: 7}, 
 { $push: { 
      notes: { 
        note_id_6: { "description": "it works", "done": true}}}})
```

Also `$push` works on arrays. So if:

```
> db.todos.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c6e4a86929336e097b18d6"),
    "list_id" : 7,
    "notes" : [
            {
                    "note_id" : 3,
                    "description" : "it works",
                    "done" : true
            }
    ]
}
```

The way to add is:

```
> db.todos.update({list_id: 7}, {$push: {notes: { "note_id": 4, "description": "doesn't works", "done": false}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: did that, no longer throws the syntax error but now says ` "The field 'notes' must be an array but is of type Object in document`, should I convert `notes` to an array or is there a way to access the subsets of an object?